# Laravel/PHP: Class cors does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, cors

I'm having trouble on some of my api calls. I was able to bypass this initial problem by using [laravel cors by fruitcake](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) -

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

But the problems didn't stop there, some api calls threw this error

> "error":"Class cors does not exist","debug":{"code":-1,"line":767,"trace":[{"file":"/home/xxxxxx/Workspace/xxxxxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php","line":767...]}

I was able to follow the instruction from the [fruitcake/laravel-cors](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) including adding it to kernel.php, created config/cors.php with the paths set to `'paths' => ['api/*'],` and finally adding this on my routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function() {
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->namespace('Api')->group(function () {

     
        Route::middleware('admin')->prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function() {
            Route::get('dashboard/statistics', 'DashboardController@index');

...
```

I'm using an older version of Laravel (5.6) and PHP 7.4. Help would be much appreciated!

When I opened the endpoint on a new tab, an error appears:

`Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message`

Comment: Also trying to clear cache - `php artisan cache:clear` and config `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 1):

Add `HandleCors` class into `config/app.php` alias section like below.

```
'cors' => \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but unfortunately the problem wasn't fixed.

Comment: I also ran `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear` but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: It works after add this alias and `php artisan route:cache`. Laravel 8

Answer (score 1):

This can happen after upgrading your laravel application.

You have to replace **\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class** in the middleware array of the App\Http\Kernel.php with

```
\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
```

It will now be:

```
protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
```

Comment: This is correct answer if you are upgrading from Laravel 9 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the `composer dump-autoload` command after adding `HandleCors` to the `config/app.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the middleware on my router

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function() {
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->namespace('Api')->group(function () {

 
        Route::middleware('admin')->prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function() {
            Route::get('dashboard/statistics', 'DashboardController@index');

...
```

to just

```
Route::middleware('admin')->prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('dashboard/statistics', 'DashboardController@index');
```